# Django: One url for multiple parameters

Tags: django, django-urls

I am trying to implement a url that can handle multiple parameters. For example:

- if i want to get the project with id 1 => `project/1`
- if i want to get the project with id 2 => `project/2`
- if i want to get the project with id 1 and 2 => `project/1/2`
- if i want to get the project with id 1, 2, and 3 => `project/1/2/3`

Is there any way I could implement this logic without hard coding N urls for N possibilities?

Comment: I don’t know how to define a url with arbitrary parameter, but if you can go with `project/1:2:3/` and split the url parameter in view function, then  `project/<id_list>/` should work

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
re_path(r'^project/(?P<id_list>[1-9][0-9]*(?:/[1-9][0-9]+)*)$', your_view),
```

and then in your view split the id list again:

```
ids = id_list.split('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple URLS using the sane view, and once the view starts they can interrogate their own kwargs.

```
path('project/<first:int>/<second:int>/<third:int/', MyView.as_view(), name='project_3args'),
path('project/<first:int>/<second:int>/', MyView.as_view(), name='project_2args'),
path('project/<first:int>/', MyView.as_view(), name='project_1arg'),
```

(The order may matter, put the longest first. Have never done this)

In the view, something like

```
third = self.kwargs.get('third', None)
if third:
    # process 3-arg form
```

You do need one url for each number of arguments.

Alternatively there's nothing wrong with Boldewyn's use of `re_path` if you want just  one argument that's a slash-separated list with no (small) limit on how many items.

Finally there's also request.GET if you decide to use something like

```
/project_foo/?item=1&item=47&item=97
```

`request.Get.getlist('item')` will return `['1','47','97']`. GET Querystrings are the most general, in that absolutely anything can be supplied in bite-sized pieces this way.